# Short educational films with a superhero

Tags: story-identification, educational

I'm looking for a short educational film or films that I saw in the early 1980s.  (I think that I saw two separate films featuring the same main character, but I am not absolutely certain.)  They featured the animated adventures of a costumed superhero character; I remember him as having an outfit with grays and other dark colors, like Batman of Black Bolt.

The movies had very simple morals, of which I only remember one, which was about not talking to or taking candy from strangers.  Somehow, the protagonist ends up on another planet where there are a bunch of creepy adults (not initially seen, as they are all in their cars) who treat him as a child.  There is then some expository narrative explaining that people on this planet average about ten feet tall, complete with a lineup-type shot with the protagonist (at about six feet) shown next to a much taller alien adult.  Since he is diminutive by the planet's standards, he is taken for a child.

That's all I remember.  I am pretty sure that I saw this in school around 1982 to 1984.  It would probably have been shown on a film projector, since I do not think my elementary school at that time even had a VCR.

Comment: This sounds as [creepy as hell](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NightmareFuel).

Comment: It could possibly be SuperFriends. I have no idea what SuperFriends is exactly, but I have heard about it, and it was made around the 80s I think, so that might be it. I think it matches your description mostly.

Comment: @DarthVader *side eye as he tries to figure out if he's serious*

Comment: I watched a lot of *Super Friends* when I was a kid, so I doubt that was it.  On the other hand, this might have been before I started watching *Super Friends*, and the show did have some cheesy morality play segments (although those usually involved a superhero instructing teens not to do something stupid).  And one of my previous questions did indeed turn out to he an episode of the *Super Friends*:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175187/trying-to-remember-1980s-fantasy-cartoon

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I am completely serious.

Comment: @DarthVader: Ah. Alright. Superfriends occasionally gets mocked pretty mercilessly (sometimes for good reason), so I was not certain.